# Domain name not working but ip does (domain google)

Tags: raspbian, google-domain-api

(sorry for my bad english)

I did the follow istructions:
https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6147083?hl=it
(i made a dynamic dns)

i made a script in linux with: 
https://username:password@domains.google.com/nic/update?hostname=www.systemcamera.org

i hoped it's ok, but the domain doesn't works, when i type www.systemcamera.org doesn't works, but when i type the ip address it's works

in the script i typed:

> wget
>   https://username:pswd.google.com/nic/update?hostname=www.systemcamera.org
>   -O dns_update_result$

i runned (./script), but i don't find my website

the result when i run the script:

> --2018-06-26 13:14:31--  https://5RodFTlBOsTBB1gL:*password*@domains.google.com/nic/update?hostname=www.systemcamera.org
>   Resolving domains.google.com (domains.google.com)... 172.217.23.110, 2a00:1450:4002:800::200e
>   Connecting to domains.google.com (domains.google.com)|172.217.23.110|:443... connected.
>   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
>   Authentication selected: Basic realm="Google Domains Dynamic Dns (www.systemcamera.org)"
>   Reusing existing connection to domains.google.com:443.
>   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
>   Length: unspecified [text/plain]
>   Saving to: ‘dns_update_results.txt’

dns_update_results.txt              [ <=>                                                    ]      19  --.-KB/s    in 0s

Comment: wget https://username:pswd.google.com/nic/update?hostname=www.systemcamera.org -O dns_update_results.txt *

Comment: Interesting sidenote, technically a URL and an IP are the same if you consider how IPs can be used to connect to webpages the same way.

Comment: The A record for www.systemcamera.org currently points at 79.44.226.150 with a TTL of 60 seconds. Is this the correct address?

Comment: @Phylogenesis yeap it's correct